# Is 5-5-2 NPK fruit tree fertilizer suitable for indoor fiddle leaf fig tree?

Tags: fertilizer, figs

I read that the best NPK ratio for indoor fiddle fig tree is 3-1-2. I have a fruit tree fertilizer with the ratio of 5-5-2. Can I use it instead? How far away from the ideal ratio is safe to go? Is there a rule of thumb?

Comment: The only fertilizer I have used is 9-45-15, in sparing amounts . Fig is outside 8 months and inside 4 months. I cut off about 3 ft. each fall.

Comment: FYI, 3-1-2 is 24-8-16 divided by 8 (so 24-8-16 All-purpose Miracle Gro would be easy to repurpose there, if it's just about the NPK numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phosphorus level is too high for your fig houseplant and so is the nitrogen, so I wouldn't use it, I just use Baby Bio houseplant food  for non flowering houseplants. Fruit tree fertilizer is balanced to encourage flowering and fruiting.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering too. I added fruit tree fertilizer from dr earth 5-5-2 to my fiddle leaf fig and I'll see what happens. If it works I'll be so happy.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33245)